# WPF DataBinding: Using SetCurrentValue in CLR property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a custom WPF `DependencyObject` which owns a property *DependentValue*. *DepedentValue* will only ever output its value, the object never reads it. The idea is that the *DependentValue* property is bound in XAML either as a *TwoWay* or *OneWayToSource* binding and updated by the object. To bugs when *DependentValue* is assigned before the binding has completed, I would like to use `SetCurrentValue` to update the property.

The conventional CLR property would look like this:

```
public object DependentValue
{
    get { return GetValue(DependentValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DependentValueProperty, value); }
}
```

Because of the issue with SetValue, this setter should never be used from inside the object. Therefore,  I would like to implement the following CLR property:

```
public object DependentValue
{
    set { SetCurrentValue(DependentValueProperty, value); }
}
```

This works as expected, but the convention seems to imply that only SetValue should ever be used inside a CLR property. What are the issues with this approach?

For context: I have built a WPF component which can be used to conditionally link two databindings: A 'driver' value is forwarded to a 'dependent' value only if a boolean property is true. This means that the 'dependent' value is 'write-only' from the perspective of this component.

Comment: *"DependentValue is bound in XAML"* - A Binding bypasses the setter and directly calls SetValue.

Comment: You can use a DP with a PropertyChangedCallback to implement any other mechanism.